# DATEDIFF - Display result in Hours and minutes

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, time, hour, minute

I am using the below to determine the minute between two times,

```
DateDiff(Minute, [MondayOpenTime] , [MondayCloseTime])
```

For a start time of 09:00 and a Close time of 17:30 it returns the value 510

Or if i use:

```
DateDiff(hour, [MondayOpenTime] , [MondayCloseTime])
```

It returns 8,

How do i get it to return the hours and minutes like 08:30

Using the minute, and then divide by 60, gives 8.5,

**Note. I have been through many of the similar questions to this, if there is one with an exact answer i will delete this, but i cannot find any answers as of yet**

Comment: Seeing that the dates are opening times and should fall on the same day, you might be able to use `format([MondayCloseTime] - [MondayOpenTime], 'HH:mm')`

Comment: @Me.Name nice idea. You would have to convert the time to datetime though to perform direct math. That isn't allowed on the time datatype.

Comment: @Me.Name why not post that as answer? You can use my variables and it works great if you convert it to datetime inside FORMAT.

Comment: @SeanLange Good point about the `time` datatype. Main reason for not posting as an answer was the caveat of falling on the same date or not. Missed that `time`s were probably being used. Thanks for the suggestion, added it as an extra answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can calculate the hours by division as you stated. You can then use modulo to calculate the minutes.

```
declare @MondayOpenTime time = '09:00'
    , @MondayCloseTime time = '17:30'

select convert(varchar(2), DateDiff(Minute, @MondayOpenTime , @MondayCloseTime) / 60) + ':' + right('0' + convert(varchar(2), DateDiff(Minute, @MondayOpenTime , @MondayCloseTime) % 60), 2)
```

Answer (score 3):

For `datetime`(2) datatypes, the following could be used:

```
format([MondayCloseTime] - [MondayOpenTime], 'HH:mm')
```

Provided that the dates fall on the same day. (since these are opening times, that shouldn't be a problem)

As Sean pointed out: for `time` datatypes, subtraction isn't directly possible and an extra cast is needed:

```
format(cast([MondayCloseTime] as datetime) - cast([MondayOpenTime] as datetime), 'HH:mm')
```

(sidenote: format is only available on sql-server 2012 and higher)